# Creating a set of folders based on a text string

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like to create a directory tree where the folder names are based on a single user input e.g. `2017-01234`

In the above case it would be `\PATH\2017\01001-01500\2017-01234\\{A,B,C,D}`

If the user input was `2018-01234` it would be `\PATH\2018\01001-01500\2018-01234\\{A,B,C,D}`

Or if the input was `2017-01654` it would be `\PATH\2017\01501-02000\2017-01654\\{A,B,C,D}`

*etc.*

How can I split apart the user input into variables to then construct the above path?

So far I can take user input and create the final set of directories, but not the intermediate tree.

```
SET /P 1="Enter Name:"
echo %1%

SET Path="\\PATH\%1%\"
echo %Path%

mkdir "%Path%A" "%Path%B" "%Path%C" "%Path%D"
```

Comment: If you run for example `mkdir PATH\2017\01001-01500\2017-01234\A` it should also create the intermediate directories. Did you try that?

Comment: And i suggest to don't use `%Path%` in your script, it's a system variable.

Comment: *I just used %Path% as a placeholder, I will use a more descriptive name when I run the actual script.

I could create the tree like you say but I need something to split the user input up so that I know what the folder names will be. I'll add a second example to my qu which will hopefully make things clearer

Comment: This kind of thing whilst it appears at first sight to be a simple case of manipulating strings requires robust user input string verification to ensure the script functions as designed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good idea to set specifications based on *examples*; you should always *describe* the specifications.

The code below produce the desired output from your three *input examples*:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set /P "input=Enter Name: "
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=-" %%a in ("%input%") do set /A year=%%a, high=1%%b/500*500+500, low=high-499
echo md \PATH\%year%\%low:~1%-%high:~1%\%input%\etc
```

Output examples:

```
Enter Name: 2017-01234
md \PATH\2017\01001-01500\2017-01234\etc

Enter Name: 2018-01234
md \PATH\2018\01001-01500\2018-01234\etc

Enter Name: 2018-01654
md \PATH\2018\01501-02000\2018-01654\etc
```